# Random selection from mysql database with php on wamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wamp, local

I am trying to make kind of a counter strike case opener. My problem is, and I suspect that the reason is wamp, that it won't load, or that it takes so long that I am unable to get any kind of result. I read all the posts about selecting a random item from a database using mysqli and that it is really slow and not fit for use, but I don't think it would be this slow. So I am really wondering if it really is what is causing the problem, or if there is a whole different error I am missing. Thanks in advance :)

```
if(isset($_GET['iid'])) {

    $iid = rString($_GET['iid']);

    $checkOwnerQuery = $data->query('SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = "'.$iid.'" AND ownerId = "'.$id.'"');
    $checkOwner = $checkOwnerQuery->num_rows;
    if ($checkOwner == 1) {
        // OWNER CONFIRMED, CONTINUE OPENING
        $randomNmbr = mt_rand(1, 100);
        if($randomNmbr == 1) {
            while($row = $data->query('SELECT * FROM caserewards WHERE chance = "1" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')->fetch_assoc()) {

                $rewardId = $row['id'];
                $rewardName = $row['name'];
                $rewardLore = $row['lore'];
                $rewardType = $row['type'];
                $rewardAmount = $row['amount'];
                $rewardChance = $row['chance'];
                $rewardColor = $row['color'];
                $rewardImg = $row['img'];
                $rewardActive = $row['active'];

            }
            echo $rewardName;

        } else if($randomNmbr >= 97) {

            while($row = $data->query('SELECT * FROM caserewards WHERE chance = "97" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')->fetch_assoc()) {

                $rewardId = $row['id'];
                $rewardName = $row['name'];
                $rewardLore = $row['lore'];
                $rewardType = $row['type'];
                $rewardAmount = $row['amount'];
                $rewardChance = $row['chance'];
                $rewardColor = $row['color'];
                $rewardImg = $row['img'];
                $rewardActive = $row['active'];

            }
            echo $rewardName;

        } else if($randomNmbr >= 95) {

            while($row = $data->query('SELECT * FROM caserewards WHERE chance = "95" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')->fetch_assoc()) {

                $rewardId = $row['id'];
                $rewardName = $row['name'];
                $rewardLore = $row['lore'];
                $rewardType = $row['type'];
                $rewardAmount = $row['amount'];
                $rewardChance = $row['chance'];
                $rewardColor = $row['color'];
                $rewardImg = $row['img'];
                $rewardActive = $row['active'];
            }
            echo $rewardName;

        } else if($randomNmbr >= 90) {

            while($row = $data->query('SELECT * FROM caserewards WHERE chance = "90" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')->fetch_assoc()) {

                $rewardId = $row['id'];
                $rewardName = $row['name'];
                $rewardLore = $row['lore'];
                $rewardType = $row['type'];
                $rewardAmount = $row['amount'];
                $rewardChance = $row['chance'];
                $rewardColor = $row['color'];
                $rewardImg = $row['img'];
                $rewardActive = $row['active'];
            }
            echo $rewardName;

        } else if($randomNmbr >= 80) {

            while($row = $data->query('SELECT * FROM caserewards WHERE chance = "80" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')->fetch_assoc()) {

                $rewardId = $row['id'];
                $rewardName = $row['name'];
                $rewardLore = $row['lore'];
                $rewardType = $row['type'];
                $rewardAmount = $row['amount'];
                $rewardChance = $row['chance'];
                $rewardColor = $row['color'];
                $rewardImg = $row['img'];
                $rewardActive = $row['active'];
            }
            echo $rewardName;

        } else if($randomNmbr >= 60) {

            while($row = $data->query('SELECT * FROM caserewards WHERE chance = "60" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')->fetch_assoc()) {

                $rewardId = $row['id'];
                $rewardName = $row['name'];
                $rewardLore = $row['lore'];
                $rewardType = $row['type'];
                $rewardAmount = $row['amount'];
                $rewardChance = $row['chance'];
                $rewardColor = $row['color'];
                $rewardImg = $row['img'];
                $rewardActive = $row['active'];
            }
            echo $rewardName;

        } else if($randomNmbr >= 50) {

            goto a;

        } else if($randomNmbr <= 50 && $randomNmbr != 1) {

a:

            while($row = $data->query('SELECT * FROM caserewards WHERE chance = "50" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')->fetch_assoc()) {

                $rewardId = $row['id'];
                $rewardName = $row['name'];
                $rewardLore = $row['lore'];
                $rewardType = $row['type'];
                $rewardAmount = $row['amount'];
                $rewardChance = $row['chance'];
                $rewardColor = $row['color'];
                $rewardImg = $row['img'];
                $rewardActive = $row['active'];
            }
            echo $rewardName;

        } else {
            echo 'Major danger';
        }
        echo '<div class="item_img_center" style="background-image: url()"></div>';

    } else {
        header('Location: inventory.php');
    }
} else {
    header('Location: inventory.php');
}
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Is that really a **GOTO** I see hiding in that code. Not seen one of those in at least 20 years

Comment: Infinite loops do have the habit of taking quite a while to run, Did you look in the PHP error log, to get some idea why this script was running for so long. I would expect to see a `max_execution_time` exceeded error in there! Or did you just turn that off?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually I have no idea where the error log is stored on wamp and I really appreciate the feedback and suggestion. I've never used goto before, but I figured it would save me some space.

Comment: ERROR LOGS can be found in `C:\wamp\logs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want that `while` loop around your random queries, as that will keep on re-running the query every time it returns a result (i.e. forever, as those will always return a result unless caserewards is completely empty).

Try just using:

```
$row = $data->query('SELECT * FROM caserewards WHERE chance = "50" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')->fetch_assoc();

$rewardId = $row['id'];
$rewardName = $row['name'];
$rewardLore = $row['lore'];
$rewardType = $row['type'];
$rewardAmount = $row['amount'];
$rewardChance = $row['chance'];
$rewardColor = $row['color'];
$rewardImg = $row['img'];
$rewardActive = $row['active'];
```

with similar updates to all your other queries.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. Didn't realize it worked like that. +1 if I could ;)